# Spring 3.2.x, Hibernate 3.x and Java 11. Fully incompatible?

Tags: java, spring, migration, java-11

We have a huge project with a lot of obsolete code and dependencies including spring-core, hibernate, spring-security and a lot more.
Having in mind that we have to migrate this project on JDK 11.
Our first attempt was just to build project with JDK 11. In some cases it worked, but when integration tests were to run, spring(ASM) confused with bytecode. Having read answers on this topic i saw that starting from spring 5 Java 11 is supported. So updating to newest frameworks would be great decision but.. A huge amount of work needs to be done, so much that we cannot even estimate it. My answer is: Have anyone tried running spring 3 on new java versions (8 works fine) or is there an opportunity to do that. Maybe some kind of dependency replacement - to use newer ASM etc or to fork spring and make some changes there? What do you think?

Comment: Yes they are incompatible. Neither hibernate 3 nor Spring 3.x will work on Java 11. Upgrading Spring is generally a drop-in replacement... Upgraded from a 2.5 version to 5 with minor changes. Ran into some issues with no longer supported libraries (Jackson 1 to name 1) but all in all it wasn't that bad. The key is take baby steps and don't go fro 3.x to 5.1 in one step. Goto 4.0, 4.1 etc. that way the chunks of work are manageable... Babysteps...

Comment: if you think making changes to your own code is hard, making "some" changes to Spring will definitely not be better. I'd start updating your own code, and maybe splitting some parts of, to make updating easier, but that's hard to say without knowing your code. Forking Spring to update this issue is.... ambitious :-)

Comment: And people tend to use Spring-boot 1 or 2 now. I see no more starting a project in Spring 5.x only. Then your work will be only retain the parts of your current Spring 3 that do really some business work, and remove quite everything else. Expect a source code divided in size by two, and far simplier.

Comment: Thanks everyone for reply. That was exactly I expected to hear. So we decided to start migration.